# Designate PublicKey as signer in Kinobi generated method

Tags: anchor, umi, kinobi

I am writing a program in Anchor and generating a TypeScript SDK using Kinobi, and I want to use an instruction in a CPI where it is signed by a PDA. Specifically, I want to add it to a realms proposal.

When I designate an account input into an instruction in Anchor as a Signer, then Kinobi can generate a TypeScript method for that instruction. However, that instruction expects a Keypair. I want to pass in a Publickey instead, which will be the PDA signer in the CPI.

If I generate the method with verifier as Signer I get this:

```
export type SetListingStatusInstructionAccounts = {
  governanceEntry: PublicKey | Pda;
  config: PublicKey | Pda;
  verifier: Signer;
  governanceProgram: PublicKey | Pda;
  governance?: PublicKey | Pda;
};
```

In this case I can't pass in a PublicKey.

If I set verifier to an UncheckedAccount in Anchor and check if it is a signer in the instruction body, I get this as the TypeScript signature.

```
export type SetListingStatusInstructionAccounts = {
  governanceEntry: PublicKey | Pda;
  config: PublicKey | Pda;
  verifier: PublicKey | Pda;
  governanceProgram: PublicKey | Pda;
  governance?: PublicKey | Pda;
};
```

But for this case, the generated method does not not designate the verifier account as a signer when it creates an instruction.

I was able to get around this by building a TransactionInstruction directly, passing in the AccountMetas that I need. I would like to be able to use Kinobi/Umi though.

Is there a way to force Kinobi to use a PublicKey as the type in the generated method signature, but still designate it as a signer when creating the AccountMeta array for the instruction?

Comment: Passing in the seeds and bump of the PDA should allow it to sign, while not being of type Signer. What does your #[derive(Accounts)] look like for this instruction?

Comment: The field in question in my #[derive(Accounts)] looks like this: `pub verifier: UncheckedAccount<'info>` . Since anchor doesn't automatically check if it is a signer, I'm checking if the account_info has is_signer == true in the instruction body. The kinobi generated function doesn't pass it in as a signer, so I have to create a raw TransactionInstruction without the help of the Kinobi method. I want the Kinobi method to act the same except for setting is_signer to true for my verifier account.

Comment: It does need to be passed in as a signer right? Or is there another way to verify the signature besides checking is_signer on the account_info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to handle this use case is to keep the `Signer` requirement and use the `createNoopSigner` function provided by Umi.

```
setListingStatus(umi, {
  verifier: createNoopSigner("your_base58_public_key"),
  // ...
});
```

The `createNoopSigner` function will create a fake signer with the provided public key that simply does nothing when it is instructed to sign the transaction.

By doing so, we are able to keep generating strongly typed clients so users can easily understand the requirements of an instruction.

This also enables more advanced client-generation features. For instance, with Kinobi, you can set the `isSigner` attribute of an instruction account to the string `"either"`. This will generate the `PublicKey | Signer` type requirement such that the account meta will be set as a signer if and only if the provided account is a `Signer` instance.